# Welcome Menu Bug

Tags: 2010

The welcome menu refers to the dropdown button with your name on it in SP2010.

I notice that mine happens to have duplicate items for My Sites and My Profile.

Any idea where I should begin looking? I am totally stumped here.

Comment: Are there any customizations in your environment?

Comment: quite a few, the front page was created about 5 years ago in SP2007, then we upgraded to SP2010 and manually edited the ribbon into the page.

there's Questech's Calendar webpart, a jquery marquee, and a banner webpart. Theres also a CSS file to customize the look of the page.

Comment: worth noting that only pages based on the front-page have the bug, the search results page and stuff does not have dupe links

Comment: Can you change the master page and check out if the issue still persists? If not check your custom master page for the welcome control..

Answer (score 1):

Since it does not exist on the search results page, that's a good indicator that it's an issue with your master page. Search centers use the minimal master page, not the standard one. If you added the ribbon to the master page in SPD, then I'd expect that to be a big part of your issues. I typically don't like doing those types of changes, typically 2007 look and feel should be applied to a 2010 master page vs. applying 2010 functionality to the 2007 master page.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before when I've had an iframe that incorrectly loads another SharePoint page, within a SharePoint page. This causes automatic population of certain things into the DOM (such as the Welcome Menu elements) multiple times. The reason this issue came around was because the iframe was loading it's own SharePoint artefacts, certain javascript routines were running multiple times in terms of the overall Document DOM element.

Ensure you have no SharePoint javascript that is running multiple times. Open the page in Developer Tools, and do a search and make sure things like SP.core.js aren't being explicitly loaded multiple times.

Comment: there is a _layouts/blank.js being loaded twice, think that might be it?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue but on both the custom master page and the unmodified v4.master inspecting with firebug reveals SP.UI.MyLinksRibbon.js being loaded dynamically multilple times.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.UI.MyLinksRibbon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.UI.MyLinksRibbon.js"></script>
```

I will open my own question, but I thought this might help your search as well

Comment: This would make a better comment than an answer. Please make comments comments and answers answers in the future, this can affect the question openers acceptance score.